# How can i use another component as my TipTap Editor container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i've been trying to create a description text input using TipTap in Laravel+React App. I managed to create a fully functional Rich Text Editor by following the documentation. here is my code right now :

```
// page.jsx
<Tiptap
      content={data.description}
      onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)} />
```

```
// Tiptap.jsx
const Tiptap = ({ content, onChange }) => {
    const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [StarterKit, Underline],
        editorProps: {
            attributes: {
                class: "prose dark:prose-invert prose-sm sm:prose-base lg:prose-lg xl:prose-2xl m-5 focus:outline-none",
            },
        },
        onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
            onChange(editor.getHTML());
        },
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar editor={editor} content={content} />
            <EditorContent editor={editor} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Tiptap;
```

```
// Toolbar.jsx
const Toolbar = ({ editor, content }) => {
    if (!editor) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Button.Group>
            {/* Heading 1 Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={
                    editor.isActive("heading", { level: 1 }) ? "info" : "gray"
                }
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleHeading({ level: 1 }).run();
                }}
            >
                <Heading className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Bold Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("bold") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run();
                }}
            >
                <Bold className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Italic Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("italic") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleItalic().run();
                }}
            >
                <Italic className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Underline Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("underline") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleUnderline().run();
                }}
            >
                <Underline className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Striketrough Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("strike") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleStrike().run();
                }}
            >
                <Strikethrough className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Bullet List Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("bulletList") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleBulletList().run();
                }}
            >
                <List className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Numbered List Toggle Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={editor.isActive("orderedList") ? "info" : "gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().toggleOrderedList().run();
                }}
            >
                <ListOrdered className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Undo Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={"gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().undo().run();
                }}
            >
                <Undo className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>

            {/* Redo Button */}
            <Button
                size={"sm"}
                color={"gray"}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    editor.chain().focus().redo().run();
                }}
            >
                <Redo className="w-4 h-4" />
            </Button>
        </Button.Group>
    );
};

export default Toolbar;
```

**Question Number 1**
But now I'm using flowbite react and By default the TipTap editor container is using div. I want to change the div into flowbite react `<Textarea />` how do i managed to do it?

**Question Number 2**
I notice every time i press Enter while make an ordered/unordered list, the item list won't continue the previos list. What could cause the problem?

**Question Number 3**
How to insert it into the Database? What should be the type of the field that will contain it?

I'm sorry for asking too much.. Hope some one could help :-)